# test iPhone app without an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, mobile

I've been sent an [iPhone app package](http://festivals.ie:8080/Festivals.ie.zip) (.zip file) that I would like to test. The app is not yet available in the app store and I don't own an iPhone. What are my options for testing this app? I can probably get my hands on a Mac (with some difficulty), but ideally I'm looking for a way of running the app under windows/Linux.

I was hoping to find a website that would allow me to upload the package, and I could then test the app in a browser, but haven't found anything like this so far.

Comment: U can upload it on testflight ... https://testflightapp.com/

Comment: Even if you get a mac you'll still need the source to deploy it to the simulator. The reason being it needs to be compiled to x86 not arm to run, for the same reason I find it highly unlikely you'll find any other simulator, at least one that's relatively accurate.

Comment: @IronManGill he will still require an iOS device to deploy it to

Comment: what's inside the zip file? ipa or the actual code?

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS no source code, only binaries

Answer (score 1):

You try what you want, the app code will not run on any other platform then an iOS device.

The best option is the get the source code so you can run the app on a Mac with Xcode and the iOS simulator.
But this is no real replacement for device testing.

Also be aware that iOS ad-hoc app arre linked to device and can there not be installed on device which are not in the profile with which the app is build. The devices are identified by there UDID.

---

The app you linked is indeed an ARM only binnary and can only be installed on devices that are in the profile used to build the app.

```
Festivals.ie: Mach-O executable arm
```

I also took a look at the app bundle and it seems that the app is native, there for you can not simply extract any thing an present it as a webpage. There is no known app to HTML tool available.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test an iOS app the developer of the app must add your UDID to his Member Center under devices. Without that limit everyone could share apps around the globe with no real use for the appstore.

There's no way for you to test it, even if you'll get a Mac and an iPhone.

Comment: How does an iOS developer normally test his app before it's released?

Comment: On the simulator, on his device, on other people devices (as long as he added there UDID to his account as beta testers)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the file you linked to. .ie extension? That's not a normal app package \ wrapper.

Comment: the complete filename is `Festivals.ie.app`

Comment: @MatthiasBauch you are right, thanks. My answer still stands.

Answer (score 0):

If not an iPhone, you can test it on an iPad or an IOS simulator... NO other way possible at all...